# Present a ComboBox as TextBlock in WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, combobox, controltemplate

I want to display a ComboBox as TextBox (without border, background, toggle button, ect.) - only current selected item text.
I do like this, but I can not understand how to link TextBlock, so that it displays the currently selected item in the ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=...}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=...}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id">
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ?}"></TextBlock>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=...}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=...}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id">
<ComboBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MyText,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ComboBox.Template>
```

Comment: This solution displays the selected item as TextBlock correctly but you can not select a new item.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `TargetType` in `ControlTemplate` and bind to `SelectionBoxItem`
Use this:

```
 <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Template>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" IsSelected="True" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="sdff" />
  </ComboBox>
```